# Mysql escaping text

Tags: mysql, text, escaping

Im sure I am doing this incorrectly.  This is probably super easy.

I need to escape text.

PHP

```
$txt = "amazonS3_info";
            $res = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM c7f_postmeta WHERE post_id ="'.$getid.'"  AND meta_key = \'\'.$txt.\' ');
```

Im sure its primarily just the escaping of the $txt which is the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you simply trying to do the same thing, you just did with `$getid`?

```
$txt = "amazonS3_info";

$res = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM c7f_postmeta WHERE post_id = "' . $getid . '"  AND meta_key = ' . $txt);
```

Comment: Get ID is an Integer though, while $txt is Text, so it has to be escaped.

Comment: Ok.. You are correct. Made the change and yes its just a simple "'.$txt.'" overthinking the problem.